# ubuntu package dependency error

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu

Webmin was upgrading packages and something went wrong after that and now i cannot install anything. Even my apache server is down . When i type

```
apt-get install apache2
```

i get this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-mpm-worker (= 2.2.22-6ubuntu2.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                    apache2-mpm-prefork (= 2.2.22-6ubuntu2.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                    apache2-mpm-event (= 2.2.22-6ubuntu2.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                    apache2-mpm-itk (= 2.2.22-6ubuntu2.3) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-6ubuntu2.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

then i ran `apt-get dist-upgrade`
and got this

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libtiff4 libxml2 rpm-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

please help

Comment: maybe you should try `apt-get install apache2`?

Comment: It would help to know which versions of apache2.2-common you have currently installed.

Comment: sorry that is a typing error . Actually i did use apt-get install apache2

Comment: Have a look into the answers on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) (especially `sudo apt-get clean`)?. Also your question is about `apt` not about `apache`, you should correct the tags accordingly.

Comment: Yes i did but no luck

Comment: You can try the below command to upgrade Ubuntu to a newer release you have to run in terminal

"sudo do-release-upgrade"